# Trying to learn how to python have, I am curious about appeand and dictionaries...am i doing this correctly?

Tags: python

posNumAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers in the list that are greater than zero.

·nonPosAvg(numList) : takes a list of numbers and returns the average of all the numbers   in the list that are less than or equal to zero.

Write a program that asks the user to enter some numbers (positives, negatives and zeros).

Your program should NOT ask the user to enter a fixed number of numbers. Also it should NOT   ask for the number of numbers the user wants to enter. But rather it should ask the user to enter a few numbers and end with -9999 (a sentinel value). The user can enter the numbers in   any order. Your program should NOT ask the user to enter the positive and the negative numbers separately.

Your program then should create a list with the numbers entered (make sure NOT to include the sentinel value (-9999) in this list) and output the list and a dictionary with the following Key-Value pairs (using the input list and the above functions):

·        Key = 'AvgPositive'  :  Value = the average of all the positive numbers
·        Key = 'AvgNonPos'  :  Value = the average of all the non-positive numbers
·        Key = 'AvgAllNum'  :  Value = the average of all the numbers

my code I have below...How do I get my third function working?

```
def nums():
    values = []

    while -9999 not in values:
         x = int(input("Enter any amount of numbers or -9999 to quit: "))

     values.append(x)
     values.remove(-9999)

     return values

def allNumAvg(values):
     average = 0
     sum = 0
     for n in values:
         sum = sum + n
         average = sum / len(values)

     return average

 def posNumAvg(values):
     x = []
     average = 0
     sum = 0

    if int in values > 0:
         x.append(int)

    print(x)

print(posNumAvg(nums()))
```

Comment: `allNumAvg` works fine..

Comment: I am talking about the third function. in particular...sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the corrected `postNumAvg` function:

```
def posNumAvg(values):
    x = []
    average = 0

    for i in values:
        if i > 0:
            x.append(i)
    average = sum(x) / len(x)

    return average
```

Python actually have a `sum` function, which returns the sum of the elements in a list. So, use it!

You can also do this in a shorter way:

```
def posNumAvg(values):
    pos = [v for v in values if v > 0]
    return sum(pos) / len(pos)
```

For the negative numbers, reverse the conditional:

```
def negativeNumAvg(values):
    x = []
    average = 0

    for i in values:
        if i < 0:
            x.append(i)
    average = sum(x) / len(x)

    return average
```

Make sure you return the result at the end of your function!

After all your functions works properly, you can store them in a dictionary:

```
def store(values):
   return {'AvgPositive':posNumAvg(values), 'AvgNonPos':negativeNumAvg(values), 'AvgAllNum':allNumAvg(values)}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still curious as to what it is trying to get me to do for the dictionary / key segment, however. I don't necessarily need an answer, though one would be nice but an explination would be very helpful. I litterally have no one in real life to ask these questions too so thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, but do I not need to do anything with the dictionary was my biggest question? I understand how to store them...Your answer was super helpful.

Comment: No, i think you don't need to do anything with the dictionary. I think it's just an extra assigment by your prof :)

Comment: change `v != 0` -> `v > 0`. btw, in Python 3.4: `posNumAvg = lambda values: statistics.mean(x for x in values x > 0)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks a lot! BTW that's quite  neat.. i haven't explored 3.4 yet :D

Answer (score 2):

```
values = []

while -9999 not in values:
     x = int(input("Enter any amount of numbers or -9999 to quit: "))
```

will never end. At the beginning `values` is empty and hence you enter the loop; inside the loop values never changes, hence you are trapped there.

You want perhaps something like this:

```
values = []
while True:
     x = int(input("Enter any amount of numbers or -9999 to quit: "))
     if x == -9999: break
     values.append(x)
return values
```

The average function looks good, although it would be easier and maybe more idiomatic to write:

```
def allNumAvg(values):
    return sum(values)/len(values)
```

And similarly the average of positive terms:

```
def posNumAvg(values):
    positives = [x for x in values if x > 0]
    return sum(positives)/len(positives) #or print to follow your example
```